# Cannot load static content

Tags: support, design, images

it seems that I cannot load the static content from the CDN just for stackoverflow.

Have I done something wrong ? It's like that since yesterday, but it was OK when I tried at my office. I'm using Google's public DNS as a primary DNS (8.8.8.8)

[image: screenshot]

**Edit :** when I use any other computer on the same network it works fine.
It looks like some software is blocking the connection. I tried disabling the anti-virus (Nod32) but it didn't helped. I've tried FF, Opera, IE, Chrome and it's like that in all the browsers.

Comment: What's the actual error on that bottom right window?

Comment: Proxy? Corporate Network? Firewall? Can you ping `69.174.57.102`?

Comment: I've seen the back-most example (no CSS, images) several times in the last few days.

Comment: I've just find out that it happend just on my Desktop PC, and I can't find what's bocking it :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOD32 uses kernel protection.  Therefore, check other agents installed in your system.

Also note to triple check these areas:

- Firewall ( Advanced options )
- Network Interface Controller settings ( NOD may alter these settings to provide early warning features and active user protection )
- Group Policy settings.

All these areas drastically affect your networking user experience.

Best of all, simply contact the IT department of your company.

Comment: thanks, I will check them all as soon as I can, but this happens at home there's no IT department :)

Comment: I tried disabling completely windows firewall - still doesn't works.

Comment: @Teneff, then it seems like there might be some kind of Internet Service Provider related issue :( Of course, you can run wide amount of Internet Connection tests, but they all will fail just because you have issue in particular Agent. It is blind shoot, but have you viewed your about:config in Google Chrome?

Comment: @Teneff Sorry for the off-topic comment but your remark that "at home there's no IT department" brings nostalgic feelings about all these "Contact your network administrator" messages I've seen on my home PC ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> when I use any other computer on the same network it works fine. It looks like some software is blocking the connection. I tried disabling the anti-virus (Nod32) but it didn't helped. I've tried FF, Opera, IE, Chrome and it's like that in all the browsers.

This is almost certainly not a problem with our network or servers, then.

If you have tried other browsers, that means it must be something between the browser and us, that is:

- proxy
- firewall
- some other software on the PC
- some other upstream network device