# Screen rendering problem

Tags: support, serverfault

I'm getting the following on logging onto ServerFault or StackOverflow with IE8:

[image]

Any ideas? meta.stackoverflow.com is fine.

Comment: It appears to be WinGate proxy related - disable proxy and the screen renders okay meta.stackoverflow.com works with either proxy enabled or disabled

Comment: I get the same thing in IE8 but not in FireFox. It's a proxy issue.

Comment: Sometimes I get a similar page using my Mac.

Comment: This is most likely a Duplicate: [Cannot load static content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96383/cannot-load-static-content).

Comment: I see this sometimes on my Blackberry.  It appears to be related to slow load times, but not a problem w/ SO specifically.