# Log in and rendering problems with Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

### When I switch from a normal public SE site to *area 51* I am not automatically logged in.

#### Moreover, the *Area 51* page is displayed with some text based formatting, but without frames or pictures.  Or, if I do get a normally rendered page, my next click to log-in, or to another page on *Area 51* renders in the weird formatted text only mode (see pictures below).

Trying to log in from the non grapichs based page by entering `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` in the `manually enter your openID feild` produces the error: `Unable to log in with your OpenID provider`

I'm running Linux Mint KDE 16, with chromium.  The bug persists in incognito mode.  And the rendering issue occasionally appears in Firefox as well; however I don't have the same log-in issues with Firefox.

**Example of page displayed when visiting Area 51:**
[image: Text formatting only example]

**Example of page displayed when trying to log in.  Note that there is no logo's to click on to log in:**
[image]

**Example of display issue in Firefox while loged in:**
[image]

---

<sub>Related issues with solutions that do not solve this question's problem:</sub>

<sub>[Can't log in to Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210771/cant-log-in-to-area-51)</sub>

<sub>[Trouble with Area 51 Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104622/trouble-with-area-51-login)</sub>

<sub>[Oops! Something Bad Happened to chat…and login…again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166413/oops-something-bad-happened-to-chat-and-login-again)</sub>

<sub>[Screen rendering problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96601/screen-rendering-problem)</sub>

Comment: Your problem is HTTPS; the CSS and images for A51 are served over HTTP, and cannot be embedded onto an HTTPS page. Disable HTTPS Everywhere for SE and everything should be fine.

Comment: I did, and it's not HTTPS everywhere, it's chrome/chromium: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en

Comment: Also, while "allowing unsafe scripts" fixed the picture rendering, it did not fix the log in issue.

Comment: In that case, I don't know.

Comment: @michaelb958 turns out the login issue is https everywhere

Comment: Well there you go. I'm trying to find a viable duplicate, but [it isn't letting me...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221460/223030)

Comment: @michaelb958 I think the chromium sheild issue is actually new; perhaps referencing the https everywhere question in my answer is a better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to michaelb958 for pointing me in the right direction; it appears this question is a partial duplicate of: [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS-Everywhere plugin is active - apparent protocol mismatch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active)

This appears to be due to poor coding practices that were caught by a combination of 'https everywhere' and built-in security detection for 'chromium' / 'chrome'

To work around these issues one can do the followng:

#### To restore pictures:

- In the address bar click on the unsafe content shield icon: [image: unsafe content icon]
- Click the link to `load unsafe scripts`
- reload the page

#### To restore log-in:

- In the address bar click on https everywhere symbol: [image: https everywhere icon]
- Under 'stable rules' and 'experimental rules', uncheck the boxes next to the works 'stack exchange'
- reload the page