# Close-as-duplicate search box is overeager to detect URL schemes

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog

*Please.* If `https everywhere` is a URL, I'm a unicorn.

> [image: "https everywhere" No eligible question found at that url]
>                                    
>   [image]

If it isn't followed by `:`, it can't be a URL scheme. Searching for HTTPS-related duplicates is now officially painful.

Comment: Put double-quotes around it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That works. *\*facepalm\** Still think this wants fixing, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One instance of:

```
if (q.StartsWith("http"))
```

Changed to:

```
if (q.StartsWith("http://") || q.StartsWith("https://"))
```

With you in the next build (meta rev 2014.2.17.1960, main rev 2014.2.17.1375)