# How do I get past Area 51's open ID authentication failure?

Tags: bug, area-51, stack-exchange-openid

While attempting to log into Area 51 to ask a question in one of the proposed sites, I was unable to gain access through any of the OpenID options I tried (Google, Yahoo, Stack Exchange). I keep getting error messages along the lines of "Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:"

Here's a full message, with some data redacted:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The openid.return_to parameter (http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s={sid}&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id)  
does not match the actual URL (https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s={sid}&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2014-11-29T21{nonce}&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3D3f7aa21d-7a4a-45a9-a419-a184230224fd%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9Xc1p6ilEXNEWsbdopViz9XWZkZ7VblAC4U4GLzdo-iM9RZCjYleRIYrqHs&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias4%2Cext1.value.alias4&openid.sig={sig}&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawm9zK_z8vWmGXGzxHoXKnSvSdU16AZqxm4&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawm9zK_z8vWmGXGzxHoXKnSvSdU16AZqxm4&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.alias4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.alias4={my email}%40gmail.com) 
the request was made with.
```

Is this a fault with Area 51 or my web browser (Tor/Firefox)? (The issue doesn't occur on other SE sites.) How do I get into Area 51 with my existing Yahoo/Gmail/SE account details? Could this be related to ["I can't login with stackexchange OpenId when HTTPS Everywhere plugin is active"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active) or ["Login and rendering problems with Area 51"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221459/log-in-and-rendering-problems-with-area-51?rq=1)?

Comment: I don't think that SE will _ever_ support logins from inside Tor network. Whether Tor is really guilty here? I dunno.

Comment: Up until about half an hour before posting the question, I haven't had issues with SE through Tor except for the occasional caching issue which causes Firefox to prevent login.

Comment: then it's probably not a Tor issue, but the very same issue others have spotted zillions of times (including me couple times) for which the only answer is: take a rest, clean cookies, logout from all SE sessions, ... just do _something_ and it will magically work again. However, _abracadabra_ seems not to be the right _something_ and nobody knows the right _something_.

Comment: [flippant]Smashing things probably doesn't help, either ...[/flippant] I suppose that if I was a _normal_ human being (whatever those are), I'd probably be out attempting to hit on women or getting a good night's sleep instead of filing bug reports (but software is far more interesting and rewarding) ...

Comment: I tried what @tohecz suggested (clean cookies, logout from all SE sessions, ... just do _something_) to no effect. To other browsers it is, then ...

Comment: Are you using HTTPSEverywhere? If so, then it is very likely causing issues.

Comment: Yes, but it's not causing issues in Chrome (only FF/Tor).

Answer (score -4):

This is definitely a Firefox issue. Abandon Firefox and derivatives for accessing SE sites. Chrome/Chromium (in incognito mode, with HTTPs anywhere) doesn't throw up any issues.

Comment: I use the Tor Browser (Firefox), and to say to abandon what is very likely one of the two most-used browsers in the Stack Exchange network user base, can hardly be acceptable as a solution.

Comment: Well, if you don't like it, feel free to offer an alternate solution.