# Server of statics (and thus CSS) is now HTTPS

Tags: support, cdn

This is related to: [Cannot load static content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96383/cannot-load-static-content)

Now that your CSS are hosted on a server asking for HTTPS, the company where I work filters it (HTTPS is authorized by whitelist only). I think a lot of companies do the same... Could you please put back the statics on a HTTP server?

Edit:

To be more precise, this is the link that causes our issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd">
```

Comment: that'll bring about mixed-mode content warnings

Comment: Is this question related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187204/css-for-so-site-not-showing-up-correctly why does meta work fine but stackoverflow doesnt work?

Comment: @JonH Meta's assets aren't served from the CDN

Comment: Okay...I just don't understand the issue at hand, this was working just a week ago.  What changed that caused this to break?

Comment: @JonH The CDN assets were all switched to be served over HTTPS as part of a plan to fully support HTTPS on the network, which will naturally cause problems if a firewall blocks those requests.

Comment: @JohH: Your *company* firewall.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I will check with our network administrators if that is the case.

Comment: @JonH: A site access whitelist is commonly implemented by a firewall (perhaps in tandem with a proxy server).

Comment: The CDN is [temporarily not using HTTPS anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191338/https-problem-when-accessing-stack-overflow-in-china/191589#191589).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is something in your pipe blocking HTTPS requests - that's very bad.  We will be switching the entire network to SSL in the coming months (first offering it, then kicking users over to it automatically).

You should speak with your network admin as to why this is blocked.  Unless they are looking at your browsing (which this prevents, short of local certs), there's no reason it should be blocked.

Comment: I forget off-hand, was "insane corporate IT policies" on your list of SSL migration worries? :P

Comment: Tank you for your reply. Blocking untrusted HTTPS websites does seem sane to me, especially in certain work environments. I've asked our sysadmins to allow HTTPS for your statics' server, which will solve the issue if my request is accepted.

Nevertheless I must tell I don't understand why you need a secured connection for statics like a CSS. This is a burden for both your users, and your server, and probably for no ROI. But I might be wrong and I'd like an explanation.

Comment: After a little research, I understand that an website serving dynamic content via HTTPS, and static content via HTTP cannot be trusted by the browser who then complains.